# Fail to Deploy the Django App in the Heroku Cloud

Tags: python, django, heroku

I was trying to deploy a Django app in the Heroku following the official [instruction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python). The project structure is as following,

[image: enter image description here [3]
[image: enter image description here [2]

It's good to mention that, I can run heroku locally from the `src` folder, `heroku local web`. Also the app create works fine, `heroku create`. While I tried to deploy the app using the command `git push heroku master`,

I get the error message in the terminal,

```
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to sheltered-sea-46201.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/sheltered-sea-46201.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sheltered-sea-46201.git'
```

I see the similar question in the SOF, but, none of them seems any help. For example, I shifted the `requirements.txt` file inside the `src` folder suggested in an answer and `pip freeze` again which is ineffective. What should I need to do to resolve the issue?

NOTE:

As someone suggested to use `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`,I tried and get the message,

[image]

Comment: try `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Not working.

Comment: Which parts of this are in git? Where is the root of the git repo?

Comment: `git init` in the source and the problem is solved.